# can't remove the pyenv virturalenv symbol

Tags: virtualenv, pyenv

I believe I correctly deactivated this pyenv virtualenv, but the symbol just doesn't go away. Am I still in this virtualenv or not? This is so confusing. Pls help. Thanks!

```
(catalog-project) wjz@MacBook-Air ~ % source deactivate
pyenv-virtualenv: deactivate 3.10.0/envs/catalog-project
(catalog-project) wjz@MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Comment: It's [`pyenv deactivate`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv)

Comment: Thanks. long story short, I had to uninstall pyenv and start from scratch. this time I chose not to allow it auto initiate the virtual env.